# Error in plotting histogram from dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, networkx

I have a dictionary with `7191` keys, and the values represent the frequency of each key.

```
degree_distri = {'F2': 102, 'EGFR': 23, 'C1R': 20,...}
```

To plot the histogram, I did:

```
plt.bar(list(degree_distri.keys()), degree_distri.values(), color='r')
```

but I got this error message: 
`unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'`

Should I not use the above code to plot the histogram? If not, what would be some of the suggestions? And why is it resulting in the error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`matplotlib.pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar)** takes as obligatory paramaters two sequence of scalars: the x coordinates of the left sides of the bars and the heights of the bars. So you should use `range` to get the paramater needed, and then use **[`plt.xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks)** to set your desired ticks:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

degree_distri = {'F2': 102, 'EGFR': 23, 'C1R': 20}
keys, values = degree_distri.keys(), degree_distri.values()
plt.bar(range(len(values)), values, color='r')
plt.xticks(range(len(values)), keys)
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

Comment: I will try to find the parameter that works and that should do it! Thank you!

Comment: @syh_090 I'm glad to help! If any of the answers helped you, consider [accepting the answer that has been the most helpful to you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), it's important because it informs others that your issue is resolved.

Comment: Oh, I see. I am quite new to Stackoverflow so thanks for the advice. I have one question, since I have about a little over 7000 keys, would it be recommended to do a bar plot or should I do histograms and use binning? I am trying to graph the plot to do node degree distribution analysis. My understanding is that, histograms display continuous values and barplots show discrete values.

Comment: @syh_090 maybe you could only barplot the ones with most frequency, so you have a better visualization.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this example [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) and the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) you have to 
supply your data in a different format.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

degree_distri = {'F2': 102, 'EGFR': 23, 'C1R': 20}

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
indices = np.arange(len(degree_distri))
width = 0.6

ax.bar(indices, degree_distri.values(), width)

ax.set_xticks(indices)
ax.set_xticklabels(degree_distri.keys())
```

First set the left x coordinate for the bars, done with `indices`, an array containing the numbers 0 till the length of your `dict`. Then supply the values. The `keys` in your `dict` have to be set as axis labels, and to position the axis labels at the correct place you have to call `set_xticks` with the x positions for the bars.